# Why is the post stage of a Jenkins build failing with a "No such file or directory" when the file is clearly there?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins build that consists of many shell scripts that write to an `output.txt` in a `scripts` directory. I have clearly defined `sh "cd $WORKSPACE/scripts"` at all stages. Before this, I used `dir('scripts')` but that failed for some reason.

Now on my post stage I also clearly go into this directory:

```
post {
        always {
            dir('scripts') {
                script {
                    sh "cd $WORKSPACE/scripts"
                    sh "ls"
                    sh "cat $WORKSPACE/scripts/output.txt"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The `ls` will clearly show an `output.txt` but then when I `cat $WORKSPACE/scripts/output.txt` it will fail with this error:

```
cat: /tmp/workspace/scripts/output.txt: No such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
Error when executing always post condition:
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.check(DurableTaskStep.java:341)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.run(DurableTaskStep.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Has anyone had this happen to them before? The file is clearly there, yet it claims it's not

Comment: Your cat command is not checking for file inside scripts directory. Check the log `/tmp/workspace/output.txt`

Comment: @RamKamath it is checking it, I'll edit the question. My bad, had to remove a lot of the output as it can't be revealed

Comment: Do you have `deleteDir()` somewhere ? Could you also paste the output of `ls` command?